# jquery mobile - list with view, delete, edit, copy options

Tags: listview, jquery-mobile

I am trying to create list view with jquery mobile displaying a list of items along with options for each item (view, edit, delete, copy).

Seeing that nested lists are [deprecated](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/nested-list-alternative-now-that-it-s-deprecated), what is the cleanest way to implement this?

Ideally, would like to have the options on one line so as not to take up too much space for them.

Answer (score 2):

One option would be to use a split button listview. When you click/tap the split button a popup appears with the actions you can take:

> **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Ur5hZ/)**

```
<ul data-role="listview" data-split-icon="gear" data-split-theme="d" data-inset="true">
  <li>
    <a href="#"></a>
    <h2><a href="#">Item 1</a></h2>
    <p><a href="#">Item 1 description</a></p>
    <a href="#purchase" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-transition="pop">Purchase album</a>
  </li>
</ul>

<div data-role="popup" id="purchase" data-theme="a" data-overlay-theme="c">
        <ul data-role="listview" data-inset="true" style="min-width:210px;" data-theme="d">
            <li data-role="divider" data-theme="e">Choose an action</li>
            <li><a href="#">View details</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Edit</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Delete</a>
            </li>
            <li><a href="#">Copy</a>
            </li>
            <li data-theme="a"><a data-rel="back" href="#">Cancel</a>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

If you want the buttons in the LI, you could use a horizontal controlgroup.

> **[DEMO FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Ur5hZ/1/)**

```
<li>
    <h2>Item 1 - this is a list item</h2>
    <p data-role="controlgroup" data-type="horizontal" data-mini="true">
        <button>View</button>
        <button>Edit</button>
        <button>Delete</button>
        <button>Copy</button>
    </p>
</li>

li p {
    text-align: right;
}
```

Comment: is there an easy way to add links to the latter version (in the buttons)

Comment: also,in the first version, does this mean making a separate popup for each row or can you just feed an id in there somehow?

Comment: You can use links instead of buttons: http://jsfiddle.net/ezanker/Ur5hZ/3/, in the first version you would use one popup and keep up with which item was clicked. You could have a click event on the split button and get the id from the parent LI

Comment: you mean making the id of the parent li the same as the id of the record?

Comment: Yes, that is an option. You could also use the P tag id or even better a  custom data attribute http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/

Comment: Thanks @Omar, just trying to follow your lead :)

Comment: Well it's nice to standardize the way we post answers for JQM :)